# How do I split the content of a file into seperate text boxes?

Tags: vb.net

I have made an appointment system where the data I put in the textboxes gets saved onto a .txt file. However when I wish to see the appointment again, I want to be able to view it in the way i entered it (which is in their texboxes)
e.g. Name : Test, 
     D.o.B: DD/MM/YYYY,  ect...

`frmBooking.TextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(frmBooking.t & ".txt")` - This line of code shows all the information in one textbox.

I tried the code beneath but it shows everything  in every single text box:

```
            frmBooking.txtboxname.Text = File.ReadAllText(frmBooking.t & ".txt")
            frmBooking.txtboxdob.Text = File.ReadAllText(frmBooking.t & ".txt")
            frmBooking.txtboxfirstday.Text = File.ReadAllText(frmBooking.t & ".txt")
            frmBooking.txtboxduedate.Text = File.ReadAllText(frmBooking.t & ".txt")
            frmBooking.txtboxweeks.Text = File.ReadAllText(frmBooking.t & ".txt")
            frmBooking.txtboxbundle.Text = File.ReadAllText(frmBooking.t & ".txt")
            frmBooking.txtboxprice.Text = File.ReadAllText(frmBooking.t & ".txt")
            frmBooking.txtboxtime.Text = File.ReadAllText(frmBooking.t & ".txt")
```

Comment: It says "ReadAllText" on each line, which will obviously read all text on each line.  Are you storing the data in the file in any structured way?

Comment: Use `ReadLine` and `Split` on a delimeter for example: | Also create a new class with properties you can use. Then you can instantiate this new class and use it anywhere you want, or put them into a `ListOf` for later use or something...

Comment: If you serialize Booking Class (or List(Of Booking), it is crazy easy to save and load them in 3 lines of code.  Presumably your app/form will want to handle more than one Booking ever

Comment: @roryap this is how i save it; If txtboxname.Text.Length & txtboxdob.Text.Length & txtboxfirstday.Text & txtboxduedate.Text.Length & txtboxweeks.Text.Length & txtboxbundle.Text.Length & txtboxprice.Text.Length & txtboxtime.Text.Length > 0 Then
                File.WriteAllText(t & ".txt", txtboxname.Text & txtboxdob.Text & txtboxfirstday.Text & txtboxduedate.Text & txtboxweeks.Text & txtboxbundle.Text & txtboxprice.Text & txtboxtime.Text)  Me.Show()  End If

Comment: That's a pretty bad way of saving data in a file as it leaves a lot of opportunity for parsing errors and corruption.  I would suggest you save it in XML format, which can be validated and you can make use of .NET's extensive XML manipulating capabilities.

Comment: @roryap sorry my bad, that is the code for saving the information that has been entered into the textboxes onto the .txt file

Comment: @436f6465786572  how do i do that?

Comment: @Plutonix how do i find out whether my form is able handle what youre saying?

Comment: @roryap How do i do that? (sorry im just a beginner)

Comment: I would start by googling it.  The topic is too broad for this site.

Comment: While saving you data to .txt file, use separator between two different entries. You can use any symbol as a separator. 

While retrieving, retrieve all data in one string and use `String.split()` method to split your string apply spitted strings to respective textBoxes.